# html2canvas giving network error while save to pdf ."Download Failed - Network error"

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I am working on code which convert div to pdf using html2canvas in angular. It is not working on server. giving an error **failed network error**.

The code I am using is given below.**Please help me with the following code only**.

```
public captureScreen()  
  {  
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
      // Few necessary setting options  
      var imgWidth = 208;   
      var pageHeight = 295;    
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
      var position = 0;  
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });  
  }
```

The reference link for the above code [refrence link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-using-angular-6/)

Comment: This code is working properly in my local but when build my code using "ng build" then it won't working. It gives me the file with the following message. "Download Failed - Network error".

Comment: yes , sure Andrew

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/

Comment: https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-8-edit-add-delete-rows-in-material-table-with-using-dialogs-inline-row-operation/

Comment: https://marinantonio.github.io/angular-mat-table-crud/

Comment: https://github.com/marinantonio/angular-mat-table-crud/tree/angular_6